# Data not inserted in database after validation in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Html and PHP Validation code: "postresume.php"

```
<?php
$firstName = $lastName = $emailId = $phoneNo = $qualification = $dob = $totex = $address="";
$firstNameErr = $lastNameErr = $emailIdErr = $phoneNoErr = $qualificationErr = $dobErr = $totexErr = $addressErr = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
    $valid = true; 

    if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $firstNameErr = "*First name is required";
        $valid = false; //false
    }
    else {
        $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
    }

    //LastName Error
    if (empty($_POST["lastName"])) {
        $lastNameErr = "*Last name is required";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else {
        $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);
    }

    // validation for,email,phoneno,qualification,dob,totex,address will be same as the above

    if($valid){
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=datasubmitted.php">';    
        exit;
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

This is my Form in "postresume.php":

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <div class="label">*First Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="firstName" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your First Name." value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo  $firstNameErr; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Last Name:
        <div class="txtbox">
            <input name="lastName" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name." value="<?php echo $lastName; ?>"/>
            <span class="error"><p></p><?php echo $lastNameErr; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    // email,phoneno,qualification,dob,totex,address will be same as the above
```

PHP code for inserting data into database mysql: "datasubmitted.php"

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","geetha@99","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="INSERT INTO register (fname, lname, emailid, phoneno, qualification, dob,   totalex, address)
    VALUES   ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phoneno]','$_POST[qualifi]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[totex]','$_POST[address]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Please help me and tell me what wrong with my code.

Comment: is there an error?  either in PHP or MYSQL?

Comment: in php inserting blank data in database

Comment: your syntax is wrong... you need brackets around your variables when you use them like that.  `values ( '{$_POST['variable']}', ..`

Comment: hi friend after using bracket also its give this error
Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobbulls123\datasubmitted.php on line 124

Notice: Undefined index: totex in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobbulls123\datasubmitted.php on line 125

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobbulls123\datasubmitted.php on line 125
INSERT INTO register (fname, lname, emailid, phoneno, qualification, dob, totalex, address) VALUES ('','','','','','','','')
1 record added

Comment: that means that your `$_POST` is empty and it's not getting values from the other page.  It's hard for me to understand the layout of your code from the way you put it in your question.  Your form is not submitting correctly for some reason.

Comment: did you try print_r($_POST); on datasubmitted.php page

Comment: @gloomy.penguin that was I told in my answer and you voted me down. first understand the code before you voted down any answer

Comment: is a `meta refresh` able to pass post values?

Comment: @RamSharma I didn't vote anyone down...?  I don't even see your answer anywhere?  I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I don't know but that's the thing, I asked earlier because meta refresh just redirect to the page instead of posting data to that page.

Comment: okay.......?  what does that have to do with me? I haven't commented on anything besides what the OP had to say and the original question.

Comment: @NeeshaVictor, try to move your validation code in datasubmitted.php and post your form to that page.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin thank u so much friend this code works

Answer (score 3):

Can you alter this below piece of code

```
   if($valid){ 
         echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=datasubmitted.php">'; 
         exit; 
     }
```

into

```
  if($valid){ 
       include  'datasubmitted.php';
       echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=successpage.php">'; 
       exit;       
  }
```